# Where Clause - Two columns of Primary table mapped to single column in Sec. table

Tags: oracle

I am facing a tricky scenario.
We have two tables

Table A

```
Name            Company 
--------------------------
Honda           Accord
Honda           Pilot
Chevy           Impala
Chevy           Corvette
Chevy           Tahoe
```

Table B

```
Name            Quantity
--------------------------
Honda_Accord    20
Toyota_Corolla  10
Chevy_Tahoe     15
```

I want to fetch quantity from Table B based on Table A. 
How do I achieve this?

Comment: This is  a horrible database design. Can you change that?

Answer (score 0):

You can join the rows using the following (as suggested by [Akina](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/150107/akina)):

```
WHERE TableA.Name || '_' || TableA.Company = TableB.Name
```